# CSS Flexbox MediaQuery - Can't get divs side by side with media query... or at all for that matter

Tags: html, css, flexbox, media-queries

I'm a rookie, so... you know... sorry.
I have 5 sections. I would like them each to stack vertically when screen width is less than 640px. When screen width is more than 640px, I'd like divs 3 and 4 to be on the same row. One tangent problem that tells me I don't understand how this works. When I change div.flex-container {flex-direction: column} to {flex-direction: row}, just as an experiment, nothing changes. I would have guessed all of the divs would appear on the same row. Why does this not happen? and what do I need to do to get my media query to work?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.flex-parent-element {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

div.flex-container {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (max-width: 640px) {
       .desktop {
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       align-items: center; 
       }
}
div#HEADER {
  background-color: #00b7eb;
}
div#HERO {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
div#CONTENT {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
div#SIDEBAR {
  background-color: #800080;
}
div#FOOTER {
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="HEADER" class="flex-container" id="HEADER"> HEADER </div>
    <div id="HERO" class="flex-container" id="HERO"> HERO </div>
    <div id="CONTENT" class="flex-container" class="desktop">CONTENT</div>
    <div id="SIDEBAR" class="flex-container" class="desktop">SIDEBAR</div>
    <div id="FOOTER" class="flex-container" > FOOTER </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see any element having the `desktop` class that you're referencing in your media query: `@media (max-width: 640px) { .desktop { ... } }`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a parent div `.desktop` between the children divs `#CONTENT` and `#SIDEBAR` to apply the `flex-direction: column` and `flex-direction: row` effects.

Also, don't forget to use the `!important` property when the screen resolution changes. (to force a CSS update).

Here, the `.desktop`  will change for max resolution > 640px, that's why I'm using  `@media (min-width: 640px)`

```css
body {
  margin: 0px !important;
}

.flex-parent-element {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

div.flex-container {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: center;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
       .desktop {
       display: flex !important;
       flex-direction: row !important;
       align-items: center !important; 
       }
       div#CONTENT {
       width:100%;
       }
}
div#HEADER {
  background-color: #00b7eb;
}
div#HERO {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
div#CONTENT {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}
div#SIDEBAR {
  background-color: #800080;
}
div#FOOTER {
  background-color: #444444;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="HEADER" class="flex-container" id="HEADER"> HEADER </div>
    <div id="HERO" class="flex-container" id="HERO"> HERO </div>
    <div class="desktop">
        <div id="CONTENT" class="flex-container">CONTENT</div>
        <div id="SIDEBAR" class="flex-container">SIDEBAR</div>
    </div>
    <div id="FOOTER" class="flex-container" > FOOTER </div>
  </body>
</html>
```